AWS tracking does not work with MSO for outlook
I have a rounded button, to make it work in Outlook I have added VML but AWS tracking does not work.
If I put the link inside "" the tracking works, but the button in VML is not clickable.
If I put the link around the VML, the tracking does not work.
Do you know how I can solve it while respecting the code for Outlook?
This is the code:
<tr>
  <td align="center" class="cta_center" height="50">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <a href="#"> 
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:60px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#0000ff" fillcolor="#0000ff">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;">Botón</center>
      </v:roundrect>
    </a>
    <![endif]-->
  
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background-color:#0000ff;border:1px solid #0000ff;border-radius:50px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;line-height:18px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:250px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all; padding: 14px 28px;">Botón</a>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </td>
</tr>

